# Error amazon-ivs-react-native-player with Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, amazon-ivs

I'm using this module in a React-native project but I'm getting error while I run `npx react-native run-android`

Error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
e: file:///Users/uguraaktas/Documents/Projects/test/node_modules/amazon-ivs-react-native-player/android/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/ivs/reactnative/player/AmazonIvsView.kt:296:5 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'BUFFERING', 'IDLE', 'ENDED' branches or 'else' branch instead

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':amazon-ivs-react-native-player:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I checked the module's repository but I couldn't find a solution because it is new yet.

Comment: The error message `'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'BUFFERING', 'IDLE', 'ENDED' branches or 'else' branch instead` seems like it's giving us a hint. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ivs-react-native-player/issues/106) with the `android-ivs-react-native-player` library. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ivs-react-native-player/issues/106#issuecomment-1339142121) available. A [fix](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ivs-react-native-player/pull/113) is pending and will be included in the next release.